# A good book for Storage Networking

Tags: storage

Does anyone know a good book on storage networking?

Answer (score 2):

If you are a complete beginner then [Using SANs and NAS](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001537) is a good introduction

Answer (score 0):

SAN Storage Essentials from [Veritas](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Storage-Area-Network-Essential/Richard-Barker/e/9780471034452/?itm=4&USRI=veritas+san): I have and can recommend. It's pricey at 80 dollars so I looked on [O'Reilly Safari](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/?portal=oreilly) where there are about a dozen to chose from. You can get a free 10 day subscription so you could dip in and read a couple of those for free in 10 days.   Most of them seem to be from 2002-2004 timeframe which was when SAN's started to get popular and I don't think the basics have changed that much since then, just got faster.